# Write HTTPServletRequest stream to Datastore of Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

I am pretty new to App Engine and Java Development and try to receive a InputStream via Http Post and store it into Datastore.

To test this I use the uptime from another computer and send 10 uptime values in one stream.

Whenever I test this, the machine becomes the response with a COUNT up to 10 and a uptime value. But the Datastore Viewer has only one item stored. What am I doing wrong? I dont think this is to much data to use Memcache yet, although it is the better way and I will do it later on.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Entity uptime = new Entity("Uptime");

    BufferedReader buff = req.getReader();
    String line = buff.readLine();

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();     

    int n = 0;
    Date timestamp = new Date();

    while (line != null){
        uptime.setProperty("timestamp", timestamp);
        uptime.setProperty("value",  line);
        datastore.put(uptime);
        //Ouput for Debug purpose
        out.println("COUNT: " + n + " LINE: " + line);
        n++;

        line = buff.readLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't creating a new `Entity` object when you loop, just changing the property on the existing one.

```
while (line != null){
    Entity uptime = new Entity("Uptime"); // remove the declaration/initialization from before, create a new every loop
    uptime.setProperty("timestamp", timestamp);
    uptime.setProperty("value",  line);
    datastore.put(uptime);
    //Ouput for Debug purpose
    out.println("COUNT: " + n + " LINE: " + line);
    n++;

    line = buff.readLine();
}
```

I'm not sure how your Datastore identifies objects (is it just a Map, what is the object id, what does its `equals()` method do?) but it should distinguish them this way.

Comment: Oh my god. So damn easy and I couldn't see it the entire day. Thanks a lot. I definitely will read the Datastore documentation again and again.